# How to use python to select all rows with minimum values for each group in a table

Tags: python, minimum

| X | Y | Val | GrpID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 414995.44 | 5813554.46 | 2.848 | 1 |
| 414995.25 | 5813554.17 | 2.847 | 1 |
| 414995.40 | 5813554.39 | 2.840 | 1 |
| 414995.35 | 5813554.32 | 2.840 | 1 |
| 414995.31 | 5813554.25 | 2.840 | 1 |
| 414995.21 | 5813554.11 | 2.856 | 1 |
| 414995.15 | 5813554.03 | 2.876 | 1 |
| 414995.13 | 5813554.96 | 2.888 | 1 |
| 414976.71 | 5813526.54 | 0.768 | 2 |
| 414976.62 | 5813526.39 | 0.744 | 2 |
| 414976.37 | 5813526.03 | 0.712 | 2 |
| 414976.33 | 5813525.96 | 0.712 | 2 |
| 414976.23 | 5813525.81 | 0.728 | 2 |
| 414976.13 | 5813525.67 | 0.736 | 2 |
| 414976.08 | 5813525.59 | 0.745 | 2 |

I want the results to be as shown below:

| X | Y | Val | GrpID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 414995.40 | 5813554.39 | 2.840 | 1 |
| 414995.35 | 5813554.32 | 2.840 | 1 |
| 414995.31 | 5813554.25 | 2.840 | 1 |
| 414976.37 | 5813526.03 | 0.712 | 2 |
| 414976.33 | 5813525.96 | 0.712 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly try using the return of a groupby as argument for the slicing:

```
df[df['Val'].isin(df.groupby('GrpID')['Val'].min())]
```

Returns:

```
            X           Y    Val  GrpID
2   414995.40  5813554.39  2.840      1
3   414995.35  5813554.32  2.840      1
4   414995.31  5813554.25  2.840      1
10  414976.37  5813526.03  0.712      2
11  414976.33  5813525.96  0.712      2
```